# Trying to complie ICU by unicode on RHEL7 system

Tags: linux, c++11, gcc, icu

I am trying to install ICU from git clone repo.

I run ./cnfigure and everything seems fine.

When i go to run make I get a bunch of errors.

I am new to Linux and cannot find any fixes anywhere.

it seems to be a problem with the uarrsort.ccp but that is the extent of what i know.

Here are the errors i run into when running make:

```
   g++   ...  uarrsort.cpp
uarrsort.cpp: In function ‘constexpr int32_t sizeInMaxAlignTs(int32_t)’:
uarrsort.cpp:40:34: error: ‘max_align_t’ is not a member of ‘std’
     return (sizeInBytes + sizeof(std::max_align_t) - 1) / sizeof(std::max_align_t);
                                  ^
uarrsort.cpp:40:34: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/cstddef:42:0,
                 from uarrsort.cpp:21:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/stddef.h:425:3: note:   ‘max_align_t’
 } max_align_t;
   ^
uarrsort.cpp:40:66: error: ‘max_align_t’ is not a member of ‘std’
     return (sizeInBytes + sizeof(std::max_align_t) - 1) / sizeof(std::max_align_t);
                                                                  ^
uarrsort.cpp:40:66: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/cstddef:42:0,
                 from uarrsort.cpp:21:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/stddef.h:425:3: note:   ‘max_align_t’
 } max_align_t;
   ^
uarrsort.cpp:41:1: error: body of constexpr function ‘constexpr int32_t sizeInMaxAlignTs(int32_t)’ not a return-statement
 }
 ^
uarrsort.cpp: In function ‘void insertionSort(char*, int32_t, int32_t, int32_t (*)(const void*, const void*, const void*), const void*, UErrorCode*)’:
uarrsort.cpp:144:26: error: ‘max_align_t’ is not a member of ‘std’
     icu::MaybeStackArray<std::max_align_t, sizeInMaxAlignTs(STACK_ITEM_SIZE)> v;
                          ^
uarrsort.cpp:144:26: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/cstddef:42:0,
                 from uarrsort.cpp:21:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/stddef.h:425:3: note:   ‘max_align_t’
 } max_align_t;
   ^
uarrsort.cpp:144:26: error: ‘max_align_t’ is not a member of ‘std’
     icu::MaybeStackArray<std::max_align_t, sizeInMaxAlignTs(STACK_ITEM_SIZE)> v;
                          ^
uarrsort.cpp:144:26: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/cstddef:42:0,
                 from uarrsort.cpp:21:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/stddef.h:425:3: note:   ‘max_align_t’
 } max_align_t;
   ^
uarrsort.cpp:144:77: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     icu::MaybeStackArray<std::max_align_t, sizeInMaxAlignTs(STACK_ITEM_SIZE)> v;
                                                                             ^
uarrsort.cpp:144:76: error: ‘constexpr int32_t sizeInMaxAlignTs(int32_t)’ called in a constant expression
     icu::MaybeStackArray<std::max_align_t, sizeInMaxAlignTs(STACK_ITEM_SIZE)> v;
                                                                            ^
uarrsort.cpp:144:77: note: in template argument for type ‘int’ 
     icu::MaybeStackArray<std::max_align_t, sizeInMaxAlignTs(STACK_ITEM_SIZE)> v;
                                                                             ^
uarrsort.cpp:144:80: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
     icu::MaybeStackArray<std::max_align_t, sizeInMaxAlignTs(STACK_ITEM_SIZE)> v;
                                                                                ^
uarrsort.cpp:145:40: error: request for member ‘getCapacity’ in ‘v’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
     if (sizeInMaxAlignTs(itemSize) > v.getCapacity() &&
                                        ^
uarrsort.cpp:146:15: error: request for member ‘resize’ in ‘v’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
             v.resize(sizeInMaxAlignTs(itemSize)) == nullptr) {
               ^
uarrsort.cpp:151:62: error: request for member ‘getAlias’ in ‘v’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
     doInsertionSort(array, length, itemSize, cmp, context, v.getAlias());
                                                              ^
uarrsort.cpp: In function ‘void quickSort(char*, int32_t, int32_t, int32_t (*)(const void*, const void*, const void*), const void*, UErrorCode*)’:
uarrsort.cpp:238:26: error: ‘max_align_t’ is not a member of ‘std’
     icu::MaybeStackArray<std::max_align_t, sizeInMaxAlignTs(STACK_ITEM_SIZE) * 2> xw;
                          ^
uarrsort.cpp:238:26: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/cstddef:42:0,
                 from uarrsort.cpp:21:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/stddef.h:425:3: note:   ‘max_align_t’
 } max_align_t;
   ^
uarrsort.cpp:238:26: error: ‘max_align_t’ is not a member of ‘std’
     icu::MaybeStackArray<std::max_align_t, sizeInMaxAlignTs(STACK_ITEM_SIZE) * 2> xw;
                          ^
uarrsort.cpp:238:26: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/cstddef:42:0,
                 from uarrsort.cpp:21:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/stddef.h:425:3: note:   ‘max_align_t’
 } max_align_t;
   ^
uarrsort.cpp:238:81: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     icu::MaybeStackArray<std::max_align_t, sizeInMaxAlignTs(STACK_ITEM_SIZE) * 2> xw;
                                                                                 ^
uarrsort.cpp:238:76: error: ‘constexpr int32_t sizeInMaxAlignTs(int32_t)’ called in a constant expression
     icu::MaybeStackArray<std::max_align_t, sizeInMaxAlignTs(STACK_ITEM_SIZE) * 2> xw;
                                                                            ^
uarrsort.cpp:238:81: note: in template argument for type ‘int’ 
     icu::MaybeStackArray<std::max_align_t, sizeInMaxAlignTs(STACK_ITEM_SIZE) * 2> xw;
                                                                                 ^
uarrsort.cpp:238:85: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
     icu::MaybeStackArray<std::max_align_t, sizeInMaxAlignTs(STACK_ITEM_SIZE) * 2> xw;
                                                                                     ^
uarrsort.cpp:239:42: error: request for member ‘getCapacity’ in ‘xw’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
     if(sizeInMaxAlignTs(itemSize)*2 > xw.getCapacity() &&
                                          ^
uarrsort.cpp:240:16: error: request for member ‘resize’ in ‘xw’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
             xw.resize(sizeInMaxAlignTs(itemSize) * 2) == nullptr) {
                ^
uarrsort.cpp:246:21: error: request for member ‘getAlias’ in ‘xw’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
                  xw.getAlias(), xw.getAlias() + sizeInMaxAlignTs(itemSize));
                     ^
uarrsort.cpp:246:36: error: request for member ‘getAlias’ in ‘xw’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
                  xw.getAlias(), xw.getAlias() + sizeInMaxAlignTs(itemSize));
                                    ^
*** Failed compilation command follows: ----------------------------------------------------------
g++ -D_REENTRANT -DU_HAVE_ELF_H=1 -DU_HAVE_STRTOD_L=1 -DU_HAVE_XLOCALE_H=1 -I. -DDEFAULT_ICU_PLUGINS="/usr/local/lib/icu"  -DU_ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED= -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -O3 -W -Wall -pedantic -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -std=c++11 -c -DPIC -fPIC -o uarrsort.o uarrsort.cpp
--- ( rebuild with "make VERBOSE=1 all" to show all parameters ) --------
make[1]: *** [uarrsort.o] Error 1
```

Sorry I am a noob. any help will be much appreciated.

thanks :)

Comment: Without speaking to the actual question posed here, I advise you to install and use the ICU package(s) that are already included in RHEL 7 instead of building your own.  You might even find some or all of them to be installed already.  Supposing that you want to build programs that use ICU, you'll want package `libicu-devel` and its dependencies.  Only if you require a more recent version than RHEL 7 provides (50.2) should you consider building your own.

Comment: Thank you that clears up alot! You saved me from a massive headache. Thanks!